# Where am I leaking memory? (Valgrind) 24 bytes lost in one block

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

Each node is 8 bytes and I allocate 3 in my program (8*3 = 24) so I assume thats the memory im losing.

This is the valgrind error

```
24 (8 direct, 16 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==2381==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==2381==    by 0x8048598: mh_alloc (in /media/sf_Z_DRIVE/comp2401a4/a4)
==2381==    by 0x8048857: main (in /media/sf_Z_DRIVE/comp2401a4/a4)
```

this is the BlockType which is the data the nodes carry.

```
typedef struct {
  int  rsv;
  void *addr;
  int   size;
  char  tag[MAX_STR];
 } BlockType;
```

This is where valgrind says im losing the data.

```
void *mh_alloc(HeapType *heap, int n, char *label){ //this is the allocation function

BlockType *blk;
blk = (BlockType *)malloc(sizeof(BlockType));
blk->rsv = C_TRUE; //set block to reserved
blk->addr = blk;  //set the address to keep track of where the block is stored in memory 
blk->size = n;   // set the size of the block
strcpy(blk->tag, label); //add the name of the block


    Node *temp2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp2->block = blk;
    temp2->next = NULL;
    if (heap->head == NULL) {
     heap->head = temp2;
    }
    else{
    struct Node *temp = heap->head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
            {
            temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = temp2;
            }
     return blk; //we return blk because we assign pointers to such blocks in the main function.
 }
```

This the function called at the end to free all blocks and nodes ->

```
   void mh_collect(HeapType *heap){ //function to unreserve all elements in the array, and free each            address


    struct Node *temp = heap->head;
    struct Node *prev = NULL;

            if (temp->next == NULL){
                    printf("Only the head left");
                    temp->block->rsv = C_FALSE;
                    return;
                    }
            while(temp != NULL){
                    temp->block->rsv = C_FALSE;
                    free(temp->block->addr);
                    temp = temp->next;
                    }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: (The original question was modified)

This code looks wrong:

```
while(temp != NULL){
    temp->block->rsv = C_FALSE;
    free(temp->block->addr);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

In your loop, you don't free the node `temp` itself.  Note that this doesn't "leak" any memory, but it does leave the memory hanging around.  You may want to consider something like this:

```
while(temp != NULL){
    Node *next = temp->next;
    temp->block->rsv = C_FALSE;   // Seems useless because you are freeing it.
    free(temp->block);            // Note: temp->block->addr == temp->block
    free(temp);
    temp = next;
}
```

Also, if you ever assign to `block->addr` other than what you showed above, then that could be the cause of your leak.  I'm not sure what the use of `block->addr` is, but I would suggest removing it unless it serves some other purpose.

Comment: I am freeing a previously allocated block of memory;

addr is a pointer to the address of the block i am freeing

Comment: Since the compiler knows that `prev` is NULL, it knows that dereferencing it is undefined behavior, so it can optimize the last assignment away. It can also transform the loop into an `if` statement, because only the first iteration can be started before undefined behavior is encountered. That is, the compiler may very well compile the code in such a way that it never generates a segfault. Doing nothing is valid undefined behavior after all...